# Workload error after update Visual Studio to 17.4.0 Preview 2.1

Tags: visual-studio

Today I updated Visual Studio to 17.4.0 Preview 2.1.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
> Version 17.4.0 Preview 2.1

After that, I can't deploy my Blazor application because I got this error:

> To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: wasm-tools-net6
> To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore

I ran the command but nothing changed.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: try "dotnet workload restore --interactive"

Comment: I tried this command and it installed NET7 but my application is in NET6

Answer (score 3):

This was hiding other errors for me.

Still, I was forced to install the correct NET workload to discover the real errors. In my case, I was targeting NET7, so I ran the following in the *Package Manager Console* (from the top menu: `View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console`):

```
dotnet workload install wasm-tools-net7
```

just change it to `net6` if you target NET6.

After that, I still was seeing the same error:
[image]

Then, I ran *Clean* and then *Rebuild* commands (right click solution -> `Clean`, then `Rebuild Solution`). After this last step, the real errors appeared:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem as well after updating a few projects to .Net 7.  I  found that the problem related to the Target Framework, and Target Location of the publish profile.  Once I upgraded these from .Net6 to .Net7 publishing worked again for me.
[image]

Comment: you can run this command: `dotnet workload install wasm-tools-net6`

Answer (score 0):

dotnet workload restore --interactive then restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by installing `.NET WebAssembly Build Tools` with the Visual Studio Installer:

[image]