# Workflow error with Visual Studio 17.5 Preview 1

Tags: visual-studio

Like in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804255/workload-error-after-update-visual-studio-to-17-4-0-preview-2-1), I installed the new version of Visual Studio 17.5.0 Preview 1. It is working quit well but again I have issues with the workload.

[image]

I tried to run multiple times the command

```
dotnet workload restore
```

and then restarted the machine. When I want to `Publish` a Blazor project to the server, I always get the error

> To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: wasm-tools-net6
> To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore

I repeated this command a lot of times without success. Is there a way to fix it?